# Which codes i need to return in RESTFul API for username/password mismatch, unauthorized access, not found & inactive user

Tags: api, rest, http, httpresponse

I am building a RESTFul api using asp.net mvc core. and we have 2 scenarios/endpoints:-

1. EndPoint-1 that accepts a username and password >> validate them against a database>> return true or false.
2. EndPoint-2 that accepts a manager username + employee username >> return the employee salary incase the manager manages the employee.

So i am unsure which status codes i need to return in those cases:-

1. EndPoint-1. If the passed username and password do not match? which represent unauthenticated request?
2. EndPoint-2. If a manager request the salary for an employee he/she does not manage? which represents unauthorized request?
3. EndPoint-3. If the passed manager username has been just deleted from the database,, but the employee username is valid/active ? which represent not found?
4. EndPoint-3. If the passed manager username is valid, but the employee username is valid but has been deactivated (the employee left the company)?

Can anyone advice on the above please? which status codes i need to return and why?
Thanks

Comment: Going by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors you're going to be looking in the 400 range. In order, I would use something like 401, 403, 401, 410. That's just my personal opinion so anyone else is welcome to wade in with theirs.

Comment: @DaveyBoy Thanks for the reply.. So i will have to return (401 Unauthorized) for unauthentication error (invalid username and password)? also i will have to return (403 Forbidden) for unauthorized access (manager is requesting info for an employee he/she does not manage) ?

Comment: As long as you document the return codes for all possible events (tip - have a "catch-all error code to handle anything out of the ordinary not covered by the above scenarios), you should be OK. It is the responsibility of clients to interpret the returned data so you're in the position of power when it comes to status codes. You could use `409` for scenarios 3 and 4 (409 is "conflict")